# InsertCommand into Header Template

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Trying to insert three textboxes into the header of a gridview and with a button execute an "INSERT INTO" into the database.

In my online server database: idt is int, datetime is varchar, and col1,col2,col3 are numeric.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="SqlDataSource1"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connone %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test];"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] [datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3] VALUES @datetime,@col1,@col2,@col3;"
    runat="server">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="datetime" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col1" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col2" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="col3" Type="Double" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("@datetime").DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("@col1").DefaultValue = CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol1"), TextBox).Text
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("@col2").DefaultValue = CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol2"), TextBox).Text
    SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("@col3").DefaultValue = CType(GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol3"), TextBox).Text
    SqlDataSource1.Insert()
End Sub

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="idt">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idt" HeaderText="idt" Readonly="true" SortExpression="idt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="datetime" SortExpression="datetime" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol1" text="col1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col2">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol2" text="col2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col3">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxHeadercol3" text="col3" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove "@" in InsertParameters as follows:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters("col1").DefaultValue =     
    ((TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBoxHeadercol1")).Text;
```

this should work.